# What is the conventional way to write this Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, coding-style, excel

Is there a more compact and/or conventional way to write this?

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://carbon.brighterplanet.com/flights.txt", Destination:=Range("A2"))
    .PostText = "origin_airport=MSN&destination_airport=ORD"
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SaveData = True
    .Refresh
End With
```

Is there a reason that `Connection` is written on the first line while `PostText` is on the second line?

Comment: I don't know if I really love doing this in the first place, but you could use line continuation (`_`) to make this fit on the screen better... `With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _ Connection:="URL;http://carbon.brighterplanet.com/flights.txt", _  Destination:=Range("A2"))` (Split the lines at the `_` since this does not come out correctly in comments...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Connection` and `Destination` are required arguments to the `Add` function, while `PostText` (etc) is a property of the QT. The `Add` function will neither work without the `Connection` nor with the property passed as an argument.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221688%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174288%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for additional reference.